# R Plotting - groups of lines with known colors

Tags: r

I have done very little interesting plotting in R so I'm looking for a little help. Thanks in advance.

I have two data.frames:

```
> dim(MyDates)
[1] 371   1
> dim(SumData)
[1] 371  30
```

MyDates holds 371 Monday-Friday dates. 
SumData holds 30 different data streams aligned properly against MyDates.

The data is clustered in 6 groups defined as such:

```
groups=list(1:5,6:10,11:15,16:20,21:25,26:30)
```

I would like to create one plot with all 30 columns in SumData plotted as (I think) solid lines. The X axis must be MyDates in ascending order. I would like to color each group differently.

```
group1 = red
group2 = yellow
group3 = green
group4 = cyan
group5 = blue
group6 = magenta
```

1 plot, 30 lines, 6 groups, 5 lines/group, each group a pre-defined color.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a ggplot answer with the correct colors.

```
require(ggplot2)

ngroups = 6
dummygroup <- function(g) 
              (g * 50) + apply(matrix(rnorm(371 * 5), ncol = 5), 2, cumsum) 
SumData <- do.call("data.frame", lapply(ngroups:1, dummygroup)) 
MyDates <- as.Date(1:371, origin="2009-01-01") 
df <- data.frame(MyDates, SumData) 
dfmelt <- melt(df, id = "MyDates", variable_name = "series") 
dfmelt$Groups <- factor(rep(1:ngroups, each = 371 * 5)) 

Colors <- c("red","yellow","green","cyan","blue","magenta") 
p <- ggplot(dfmelt, aes(MyDates, value, color = Groups, group = series)) 
p <- p + geom_line() + scale_colour_manual(values = Colors) 
print (p)
```

Comment: Looks interesting and as a newbie the code is helpful, but it didn't run for me here:

Comment: @LGTrader: Seems to work fine. I added a line to require the ggplot2 package in case that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but this gets the job done...

```
require(zoo)

# z <- zoo(SumData, MyDates)
z <- zoo(matrix(rnorm(30*371),371,30),Sys.Date()-371:1)

Groups <- list(1:5,6:10,11:15,16:20,21:25,26:30)
Colors <- c("red","yellow","green","cyan","blue","magenta")

Col <- vector("character",length(unlist(Groups)))
for(i in 1:length(Groups)) {
  Col[Groups[[i]]] <- Colors[i]
}

plot(z, screens=1, col=Col)
```